# Node js Google Authentication 2 FA Implementation Otp

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-authenticator, totp, google-2fa

I want to implement Google 2FA Authentication in node js How can i do this?

I used speakeasy js library like below :

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode');
const secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({
    name: 'test'//constants.SPEAK_SECRET_CODE
});
 var qr_data = '';
  await qrcode.toDataURL(secret.otpauth_url).then(qr => {
                                qr_data = qr;
                            });
 return { qr_data };
```

After this i created html file with this code `<img src="qr_data">` and with google authenticator app i scanned barcode it worked succesfully.

Then i tried to this in order to verify google otp :

```
  var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
            secret: secret.ascii,
            encoding: 'ascci',
            token: otp,
        });

        console.log(verified);
```

But verified variable is always false,although I entered the correct code